# Printing in Django Template a Pandas dataframe with dynamic indexes and columns

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a script that creates dataframe with dynamic indexes values and name of the columns, as well as the number of columns. The only fixed value is the name of the index column that is "Transaction". Below an example.

[image]
I am passing this dataframe from a Django view to a Django Template, but I don't know how to access, in the template, the values of it.

```
def myFunction(request):
  df = myDfFunction() #returns the dataframe
  return render(request, 'reports/my_page.html', {'df': df})
```

In the template I am trying to access it in many ways, without success.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for row in df %}
    <p>         
         {{ row[0][0] }}
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with pandas, but the Django template language uses dots for property access of any kind, including dictionary keys - so try `row.0.0`

Comment: Thank you Robin. It does not work. :(

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.0.10
Exception Type: JSONDecodeError
Exception Value: 
Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)

Comment: I think we need more code - a `JSONDecodeError` means (to state the obvious...) that at some point while loading the page you're decoding some JSON data which isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your pandas dataframe to an html table and pass that to your template instead.

```
def myFunction(request):
    df = myDfFunction() #returns the dataframe
    return render(request, 'reports/my_page.html', {'df': df.to_html()})
```

and you don't need to construct a table in your html file as this generates it.